# Remove post ID from WordPress slug into separate path segment

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a WordPress site where all posts are in the form of:

```
http://example.com/category/12345-my-post-tile-is-here
```

where `12345` is the `post_id`.

I want this to be done to the following format:

```
http://example.com/category/12345/my-post-tile-is-here
```

Is it possible using `.htaccess` 301 redirect or URL rewriting using regex find and replace?

I had already tried to use custom permalink structure in wordpress settings but the result is not what I looking for.

I also tried this in my .htaccess file:

redirect 301 ^(.*)-(.*)$ /$1/$2

but the result for http://example.com/category/12345-my-post-tile-is-here is
http://example.com/category/12345/my/post/tile/is/here/

Comment: This should be done in WordPress, not `.htaccess`. (Just curious, why do you want to make this _subtle_ change?)

Comment: "12345-my-post-tile-is-here" it is the slug of my post, so i need to have clear slugs without post_ids

Answer (score 2):

Use WordPress permalink support.

You can rewrite the permalinks from WP dashboard `Settings -> Permalinks`.

1. Select custom structure
2. Change value to `/%category%/%post_id%/%postname%` and save
3. Your post will be accessible at `http://example.com/category/postid/postname`

Comment: I have already tried this. It converts my url to: 

http://myblog.com/category/12345/12345-my-post-tile-is-here.

I need to remove the post_id from slug where it was inserted manualy by typing the post_id

Comment: You can edit the post slug by editing the post. Go to `All posts -> Your post`. Just below the post title, you should be able to edit the permalink. It'll ask you for the new post slug. Click Ok and update post.

Comment: I have too many posts to do this, one by one. I have 20000 or more posts. That is why i am looking for a way to rewrite the url of these posts or redirect them in the format: http://example.com/category/12345/my-post-tile-is-here without editing the slug of each post or loosing seo score for these urls which already submited to google.